# Can I ask for salary break down while replying to letter of intent and other things?

Tags: communication, email

I have received a mail from the company for whose interview I appeared a while ago. However, during interview I forgot to ask them questions such as breakdown (*I know forgot the important thing*).

Day before yesterday I got a mail with Letter of Intent attached which I have to accept or deny. Since I'm a freshman and would go 6 month training which would be organised by the company itself.

Coming back to the mail. I have to reply them within a week. They've mentioned that if I have any queries, I can revert them back. So can I ask them things like the salary breakdown? Like what would be in-hand salary and other perks I'll be getting. And information about expected date of joining?

I don't know if such things are considered professional, therefore, little confused.

Comment: What is a salary breakdown?

Comment: Just a hint, not full answer: Ignore the one week deadline. At best it's just unprofessional to let a candidate wait for a while and then setting a tight deadline. At worst they're using it as a tactic to pressure you into a job you don't really want. I had to learn it the hard way. Let them know your own timeline.

Comment: @Kilisi I mean what would be in hand salary, what would be the perks and other allowances, etc (I believe I already mentioned in the post). Company has only disclosed cost to company (CTC).

Comment: @Kilisi I'm going to hazard a guess that it's a [tag:india] thing

Comment: @Chris ignoring the deadline makes you look unprofessional and shows the company you can't keep to deadlines, I don't think this is good advice. There is probably a reason they have put a week in place, maybe they have a lot of candidates who don't get back to them and they want to know when to pursue other avenues. A week is plenty of time to consider, I wouldn't think this was pressure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would it be unprofessional to ask what your salary would be? Would you accept a job offer without knowing what you're going to be paid? Of course not.

Reply to their email asking them what the salary and benefits are.

Comment: Okay. I'll do it. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Kulfy, In fact, I'd also ask for a final copy of the contract before I'd make any decision. The contract would have information on salary, timing, probationary period, insurance benefits, moving expenses, relocation packages, notice period, non-competes, vacation time, arbitration clauses, training reimbursement, etc.

Comment: Also, many people would ask for a copy of the employee handbook if it's mentioned in the contract as something you would be agreeing to.